# Output all negative numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, negative-number

How to obtain output of all negative numbers in the list. Here is code what I tried but am able to get only one number

```
#creat list using function
def Negative(List):    
      sum=0

      for i in List:
             if i < 0:
                 sum += i
                 return sum
#input and print list
inputData= input('enter numbers')

List = [float(i) for i in inputData.split(' ')]

print(Negative(List))
```

Comment: Look at where your `return` is located. `return` exits the function *there and then*, when do you think it is executed? How often will the `if` test be executed?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you are trying to sum the negative numbers, where your question implies that you are trying to find all the negative numbers.

Comment: I would do: [float(i) for i in inputData.split(' ') if i<0]

Comment: Yes it is testing only once.so how to run the if loop in this case?

Comment: So what changes should i do and where @DeepSpace

Comment: @O.Suleiman `i` is a string in your comparison

Comment: @SeemaShah: You should change the way you think. Don't try to get the solution from others, think how the algorithm should be.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh True, I missed the float function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a function can only return once.

> The return statement terminates the execution of a function and
>   returns control to the calling function. Execution resumes in the
>   calling function at the point immediately following the call.

so at line 8 you are returning sum and then exist. it is not going for next iteration of loop so it return first num which is true for that condition.

> Solution:

Store each iteraton result somewhere like list,dict etc and then return that at last of function.

Here you can try:

```
#creat list using function
def Negative(List):
    neg_num=[]
    for i in List:
        if i<0:
            neg_num.append(i)
    return neg_num
#input and print list
inputData= input('enter numbers ')


List = [float(i) for i in inputData.split(' ')]

print(Negative(List))
```

output:

```
enter numbers 1 -2 3 -4 5 -6 7 -8
[-2.0, -4.0, -6.0, -8.0]
```

And as you commented out:

> how to count the numbers obtained from the list??

Try this :

```
#creat list using function
def Negative(List):
    neg_num=[]
    for i in List:
        if i<0:
            neg_num.append(i)
    return neg_num
#input and print list
inputData= input('enter numbers ')


List = [float(i) for i in inputData.split(' ')]

print(Negative(List))
print(len(Negative(List)))
```

output:

```
enter numbers 1 -2 3 -4 5 -6 7 -8
[-2.0, -4.0, -6.0, -8.0]
4
```

Or if you want sum of list items as you are trying to do in your program then:

```
print(sum(Negative(List)))
```

> Additional :

You can short this for loop logic using list comprehension:

```
neg_num=[i for i in List if i<0]
```

is same as :

```
neg_num=[]
    for i in List:
        if i<0:
            neg_num.append(i)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ayodhyankit Paul :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   def Negative(List):
       return [num for num in List if num<0]
   #input and print list
   inputData= input('enter numbers')
   List = [float(i) for i in inputData.split(' ')]
   print(Negative(List))
```

Comment: Thank you @Manav Gupta:)

Comment: And how to count the numbers obtained from the list?? @Manav Gupta

Comment: print len(Negative(List)) will display the count.